# Subscriber in Hardware Interface (ros2_control)

Tags: ros2, ros2-control, hardware-interface

Is there any example for adding subscriber to hardware interface ? Publisher works fine.
My code is below, I dont know where its going wrong but unable to get values after publishing using CLI.

.hpp file
'''

> namespace diffdrive_ctre { class HardwareCommandPub : public
> rclcpp::Node {   public:
>
> ```
> HardwareCommandPub();
> void publishData();
> void pincmdcheck();
> ```
>
> private:
> rclcpp::Publisher<amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Motor>::SharedPtr pub_;
> rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::Bool>::SharedPtr estop_pub_;
> rclcpp::Subscription<amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Pin>::SharedPtr pin_sub_;
> rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
> amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Pin latest_pin_cmd; };
>
> class DiffDriveCTREHardware : public
> hardware_interface::SystemInterface {

'''
.cpp file

> HardwareCommandPub::HardwareCommandPub() : Node("Motor_Status") {
>
> pub_ =
> this->create_publisher<amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Motor>("talonFX_right/status",
> 10);   estop_pub_ =
> this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::Bool>("/e_stop", 10);   pin_sub_
> = this->create_subscription<amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Pin>("/amr/pin_cmd",
> 10,
> [this](const amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Pin::SharedPtr pin_cmd) { latest_pin_cmd = *pin_cmd; });
>
> }
>
> void HardwareCommandPub::publishData() {   // //motor1   auto message
> = amr_v4_msgs_srvs::msg::Motor();   message.temperature_right = motor_right.GetDeviceTemp().ToString();   message.bus_voltage_right =
> motor_right.GetSupplyVoltage().ToString();
> message.output_current_right =
> motor_right.GetStatorCurrent().ToString();   message.error_right =
> motor_right.GetStickyFault_Hardware().ToString();
>
> // //motor2   message.temperature_left =
> motor_left.GetDeviceTemp().ToString();   message.bus_voltage_left =
> motor_left.GetSupplyVoltage().ToString();
> message.output_current_left =
> motor_left.GetStatorCurrent().ToString();   message.error_left =
> motor_left.GetStickyFault_Hardware().ToString();
>
> ```
> // //motor pin   message.temperature_pin = pin_motor.GetDeviceTemp().ToString();   message.bus_voltage_pin =
> ```
>
> pin_motor.GetSupplyVoltage().ToString();   message.output_current_pin
> = pin_motor.GetStatorCurrent().ToString();   message.error_pin = pin_motor.GetStickyFault_Hardware().ToString();
>
> //estop   auto message_estop = std_msgs::msg::Bool();
> message_estop.data = estop_temp;   if (rclcpp::ok())   {
> estop_pub_->publish(message_estop);
> pub_->publish(message);
> pincmdcheck();   }   }
>
> void HardwareCommandPub::pincmdcheck() {   pin_temp =
> latest_pin_cmd.pin_command;   RCLCPP_INFO(
> rclcpp::get_logger("Pin test"),
> "Got pin cmd '%i'and '%i' and '%s'!",pin_temp,latest_pin_cmd.pin_command);    }

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this implementation of
topic_based_ros2_control](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control/blob/37a98e652818ac4b884786558a2f3c0373415c16/src/topic_based_system.cpp#L149) here.

Note that in general, it is not recommended to use a node inside the hardware interface if you have realtime requirements. Write your custom controller with realtime-safe implementations instead.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But your point makes perfect sense.